# Javascript how to get full two year from current month?

Tags: javascript, date

I have question about getting full two years from the current date. So what I did is get the current month using `new Date()` and used a `for` loop to print each of the months. But I can't really get it to work... I will post the code that I tried below. I would be really appreciate it if anyone can tell me the logic or a better way of doing it.

For example:
If the current date is 8 August 2020, it creates an array with the values `"8/2020"`, `"9/2020"` ... `"7/2022"`, `"8/2022"`.

```js
var d = new Date();

var year = d.getFullYear();

var dateStr;
var currentYear;

var storeMonthYear = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 24; i++) {
    dateStr = d.getMonth() + i
    currentYear = year;
    
    if (dateStr > "12") {
        dateStr = dateStr - 12

        // currentYear = year;
        // if (currentYear) {

        // }

        storeMonthYear[i] = dateStr + "/" + (currentYear + 1);
    } else if (dateStr > "24") {
        storeMonthYear[i] = dateStr + "/" + (currentYear + 1);
    } else {
        storeMonthYear[i] = dateStr + "/" + currentYear;
    }

    storeMonthYear[i] = d.getMonth() + i
}

export const settlementPeriod = [{
    MonthYearFirstRow1: storeMonthYear[1],
    MonthYearFirstRow2: storeMonthYear[2],
    MonthYearFirstRow3: storeMonthYear[3],
    MonthYearFirstRow4: storeMonthYear[4],
    MonthYearFirstRow5: storeMonthYear[5],
    MonthYearFirstRow6: storeMonthYear[6],
    MonthYearFirstRow7: storeMonthYear[7],
    MonthYearFirstRow8: storeMonthYear[8],
    MonthYearFirstRow9: storeMonthYear[9],
    MonthYearFirstRow10: storeMonthYear[10],
    MonthYearFirstRow11: storeMonthYear[11],
    MonthYearFirstRow12: storeMonthYear[12],

    MonthYearSecondRow13: storeMonthYear[13],
    MonthYearSecondRow14: storeMonthYear[14],
    MonthYearSecondRow15: storeMonthYear[15],
    MonthYearSecondRow16: storeMonthYear[16],
    MonthYearSecondRow17: storeMonthYear[17],
    MonthYearSecondRow18: storeMonthYear[18],
    MonthYearSecondRow19: storeMonthYear[19],
    MonthYearSecondRow20: storeMonthYear[20],
    MonthYearSecondRow21: storeMonthYear[21],
    MonthYearSecondRow22: storeMonthYear[22],
    MonthYearSecondRow23: storeMonthYear[23],
    MonthYearSecondRow24: storeMonthYear[24]    
}];
```

Comment: In the array you want a structure like this [M/YYYY, M/YYYY, ...] and no date-objects?

Answer (score 2):

Create the date from today, get the month and year. Iterate from 0 to 24 for now till in 24 months. If month is 12 than set month to 0 and increment the year. Push the new datestring. Increment the month for the next step.
Note: Beacsue JS counts months form 0-11 you had to add for the datestring 1 for the month and make the change of year at 12 and not 13.

```js
let date = new Date();
let year = date.getFullYear();
let month = date.getMonth();

let res=[];
for (let i=0; i<=24; i++) {
   if (month===12) {
       month = 0;
       year++;
   }
   res.push(month+1 + '/' + year);
   month++;
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Happy to help you. If you are satisfied with this than you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that stick out in your code sample:

- You're comparing strings and numbers (e.g. `dateStr > "12"`). This will lead to some weird bugs and is one of JS's most easily misused "features". Avoid it where possible.
- You increment the year when you reach 12 months from now, rather than when you reach the next January
- You're overwriting your strings with this line `storeMonthYear[i] = d.getMonth() + i` so your array is a bunch of numbers rather than date strings like you expect

Here's a code sample that I think does what you're expecting:

```js
function next24Months() {
  const today = new Date()

  let year = today.getFullYear()
  let monthIndex = today.getMonth()

  let dates = []

  while (dates.length < 24) {
    dates.push(`${monthIndex + 1}/${year}`)

    // increment the month, and if we're past December,
    // we need to set the year forward and the month back
    // to January
    if (++monthIndex > 11) {
      monthIndex = 0
      year++
    }
  }

  return dates
}
```

In general, when you're dealing with dates, you're probably better off using a library like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) - dates/times are one of the most difficult programming concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, you get an array of strings like "8/2020","9/2020" etc from starting month to the last month including both( in total 25 months).
If you don't want to include last month just delete +1 from for loop condition.

```
let currentDate = new Date();

let settlementPeriod = [];

let numberOfMonths = 24;

for(let i=0;i<numberOfMonths+1;i++){
    settlementPeriod.push(currentDate.getMonth()+1+"/"+currentDate.getFullYear()); //We add current date objects attributes to the array
    currentDate = new Date(currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth()+1)); //Every time we add one month to it
}
console.log(settlementPeriod);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i will take a look at it

Comment: Try adding 1 month to 31 January using this method.

Answer (score 0):

While @Ognjen 's answer is correct it's also a bit waseful if your date never escapes its function.

You don't need a new date every time:

```
function getPeriods(firstMonth, numPers){
  var d = new Date(firstMonth.getTime()); // clone the start to leave firstMonth alone
  d.setDate(1); // fix after @RobG
  var pers = [];
  var m;
  for(var i = 0; i< numPers; i++){ 
     m = d.getMonth();
     pers.push(`${m+ 1}/${d.getFullYear()}`)
     d.setMonth(m + 1); // JS dates automatically roll over. You can do this with d.setDate() as well and when you assign 28, 29, 31 or 32 the month and year roll over automatically
  }
  return pers;
}
```

Comment: Ognjen 's answer isn't correct. If the code is run on 31 Jan then adding 1 month will return 2 Mar in leap years and 3 Mar in other years, skipping February.